# Run ECS service task only once

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I want to run ECS task only once. I have created a ECS service which continuously runs a task.
Like if I check in the ec2 instance after first container gets executed it automatically starts another container. I don't want another container to be executed after first container execution I will close the task.

Note: I haven't created any scheduler.

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

ECS services are for constantly running tasks that need to be replaced if they fail or exit for some reason. [ECS scheduled tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html) are much more like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a task once in ECS, you can use the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html). Or check out this [tool](https://github.com/meap/runecs) that simplifies the process a bit.